# How to avoid re-entrance attacks when transferring tokens

Tags: solidity

I have a function that allows users to pay for a monthly subscription. I run slither on my smart contract I got a warning that I have a potential re-entrance attack because ***State variables written after the call(s):***

Should I move the transferFrom and sent require check to the end of the function?

```
// smart contract subscription(part of it)
struct Subscription {
        address payable subscriber;
        uint start;
        uint nextPayment;
        bool activated;
    }

    
    /* nested mapping from address to id to Subscription */ 
    mapping(address => mapping(uint => Subscription)) private AllSubscriptions;


 function pay(address subscriber, uint planId) external {
    Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
    IERC20 token = IERC20(plan.token);
    require(
      subscription.subscriber != address(0), 
      'this subscription does not exist'
    );
    require(
      block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment,
      'not due yet'
    );

    bool sent = token.transferFrom(subscriber, plan.merchant, plan.amount);
    require(sent, "token transfer failed");
    emit PaymentSent(
      subscriber,
      plan.merchant, 
      plan.amount, 
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );
    subscription.nextPayment = subscription.nextPayment + plan.frequency;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid re-entrency attack, you need to update your variables **PRIOR** to the transfer call. The code below should work. (If you still get re-entrency warning, please see if you might share entire contract code, so I can be sure I am not missing anything)

```
function pay(address subscriber, uint planId) external {
    Subscription storage subscription = subscriptions[subscriber][planId];
    Plan storage plan = plans[planId];
    IERC20 token = IERC20(plan.token);
    require(
      subscription.subscriber != address(0), 
      'this subscription does not exist'
    );
    require(
      block.timestamp > subscription.nextPayment,
      'not due yet'
    );
    
    // UPDATING Subcription prior to transferFrom
    subscription.nextPayment = subscription.nextPayment + plan.frequency;

    bool sent = token.transferFrom(subscriber, plan.merchant, plan.amount);
    require(sent, "token transfer failed");
    emit PaymentSent(
      subscriber,
      plan.merchant, 
      plan.amount, 
      planId, 
      block.timestamp
    );
    
  }
```